# Kenitico CMS not getting configured

Tags: kentico

I am configuring the Kentico CMS to my local machine but getting the following error:

> The CISM115\cis account is not granted with Modify permission on folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\KenticoCMS\`. Although this is not an error, it's highly recommended that you configure these permissions.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the persissions of that folder, so that the application can modify it's contents.